# file is being submitted automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

In the code posted below, I want to open `file-chooser` on clicking anchor tag `<a>`. The `file-chooser` open successfully but the problem is that the form is being submitted too (automatically). So please tell, how can I prevent form to be submitted?

**Code:**

```
<?php
    echo form_close();
    echo form_open_multipart('transferdata/uploadfile');
?> 
<form action = "" method = "" id="uploadForm">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" style="display: none;" />
    <a class="toolbar" href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/transferdata/uploadfile' ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('userfile').click();">
        <span title="Upload" class="icon-32-upload"></span>
        Upload
    </a>
    <input type="file" name="submitB" id="submitB" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Change the href value to `#`

Comment: Why is there an "href" value at all? Indeed, why an `<a>` and not `<button type=button>`?

Comment: you are actually submitting the data on anchor click try with a href="#"

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help You :

use either php codeigniter form or simple form

and second : remove the `href` url with `javascript:void(0)`

```
 <?php
   echo form_open_multipart('transferdata/uploadfile');
  ?> 

<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" style="display: none;" />
<a class="toolbar" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('userfile').click();">
  <span title="Upload" class="icon-32-upload"></span>Upload
</a>
<input type="file" name="submitB" id="submitB" value="upload"/>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" >upload</button>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

for Morel : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove the `display:none` from input `type=file` and  hence it is not displaying you can't click on it.

Secondly remove the submit button from form which has `type="file"` instead of `<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">`

Comment: That's not what's wrong here, the `display:none` if for a custom styles file input box and is perfectly legitimate. The problem is the href is changing header location.

Comment: Thanks @Pogrindis